# Special tree stumps?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In "Animal Crossing: New Leaf," I used my ax to cut down a tree. To my surprise, there was a Triforce mark on it! What does this special type of tree stump do? What is the probability of getting another one?

Comment: sheesh. I made it sound like a math problem...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a ['special' tree stump](http://au.ign.com/wikis/animal-crossing-new-leaf/Tree_Stumps) - they are a certainty when you cut down trees using the silver axe, but can be created by any axe type with varying probability.

Special tree stumps [can grow mushrooms year-round](http://au.ign.com/wikis/animal-crossing-new-leaf/Mushrooms), rather than only during the mushroom season.